# Is it a good practice to add text after products?

Tags: text, products

I want to add text to a category page with products. Is it ok to add 2-3 lines before the products and the rest of the text after them?

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is. Category pages should in most cases be indexed anyway, and you want to increase the chances of those showing up in search results. Thus, a few lines of reasonably optimized text will only help.

Regarding text after the products, keep in mind that if the text is too far down the page, as is often the case with product category pages that dynamically populate the products and can result in long scroll, users may never get to that text. Depending on the context, it might make sense to put all the text above the product, as long as it's not too long either.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I wanted to see. Thank you very much.